# Get latest of a column from table, grouped by another column in HQL

Tags: java, postgresql, hql

I'm having one hell of a time trying to figure out the HQL statement for this.  I'm trying to get the latest status of all product orders within a group, but can't seem to figure out the correct HQL syntax to get this working...

Example table:

```
id | created_at | group_id | purchase_id | status
---|------------|----------|-------------|------------
0  | 10         | 3        | 6           | DELIVERING
1  | 11         | 3        | 6           | DELIVERED
2  | 12         | 3        | 7           | DELIVERING
3  | 13         | 3        | 8           | DELIVERING
4  | 14         | 4        | 13          | DELIVERING
5  | 15         | 4        | 13          | DELIVERED
6  | 16         | 4        | 13          | LOST
7  | 17         | 5        | 17          | DELIVERING
```

Get the latest (by `created_at`) of each `purchase_id`, where the `group_id` = 3.  Should result in this table:

```
id | created_at | group_id | purchase_id | status
---|------------|----------|-------------|------------
1  | 11         | 3        | 6           | DELIVERED
2  | 12         | 3        | 7           | DELIVERING
3  | 13         | 3        | 8           | DELIVERING
```

Query that works in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (o.purchase_id) *
FROM orders o
WHERE o.group_id = 3
ORDER BY o.purchase_id, o.created_at DESC
```

What would the equivalent HQL statement be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumming that `created_at` values are unique within each `purchase_id`, then the below HQL should work

```
from Orders
WHERE (purchase_id, created_at) 
      IN  
      (   SELECT purchase_id, max( created_at ) 
          FROM Orders
          GROUP BY purchase_id 
      )
```

---

When `created_at` is not unique for a given `purchase_id` (one value of purchase_id may have two "latest" records with the same value of `created_at`), then a subquery at a deeper level is required - the below HQL will pick only one record with highest `created_at` then highest `id` for each `purchase_id` (this time assumming that ID is a primary key and is unique):

```
from Orders
WHERE id IN (
   SELECT max( id ) from Orders
   WHERE (purchase_id, created_at) 
         IN  ( 
           SELECT purchase_id, max( created_at ) 
           FROM Orders
           GROUP BY purchase_id 
          )
   GROUP BY purchase_id
 )
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm failing to see how this gets the most recent per a grouping of `purchase_id`?  I see you are using the fact that the latest would have the "highest" `created_at` value (or the highest `id`), but don't see how that still groups by `purchase_id`.

Comment: Thanks!  I've used the first HQL statement but just needed to add `AND o.group_id = ?` after the `WHERE...IN ()` clause to get everything working!